# How to create fake object from a data type in Typescript for testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm looking for a way to simplify making fake data for unit testing in Angular solution.
I am using interfaces like:

```
export interface ReferenceDataItemCommon {
  codeDescription?: string;
  code: string;
  deleted?: boolean;
}
```

As data types in application. Currently using Factory.ts + Faker to create fake objects for purpose of tests:

```
  export const fakeReferenceDataItemCommon = Factory.Sync.makeFactory<ReferenceDataItemCommon>({
    code: Factory.each(() => Faker.lorem.word()),
    codeDescription: Factory.each(() => Faker.lorem.sentence(4)),
  });
```

But I'm curious if there is a way to simplify it even more for when you just want a object for your test and speed up creating it even more.
Is it possible in Typescript to have a generic method that would return a object of that datatype?

```
  const fake = createFake<ReferenceDataItemCommon>();
```

What my initial idea was is to do something like:

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
  switch(typeof object[key]) {
    case 'string':
       object[key] = Faker.lorem.word();
       break;
  }
}
return object;
```

And for complex object call this method recursively. Is that possible, and if what would be a better approach to do this as I feel a bit out of my depth?

Comment: You cannot create values from types. TypeScript type information does not exist at run time.

Comment: I think this should be possible using code-generation. Where you'd create the factories with a cli, not at runtime. 

I'm currently looking for such a thing, might build it.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the factories with a cli, not at runtime it's possible:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/intermock looks promising

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something similar too but also didn't find it. So, I create this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator-mocker, which works with classes annotated with [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) decorators. If you can work with data classes instead of interfaces to define certain types, I think it's worth taking a look at it.